# Every Regular Language is a Context Free Language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

How do I show that every regular language is a context-free language?

I've been told to construct a Context-Free Grammar by Induction on the number of operators in the regular expression; but I'm still not sure.

Comment: This depends on your definition of the two types of languages —for example, if you define them using grammars, this is obvious. You should tell us what your definitions are.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, what you've been told works. The set of regular expressions is the smallest set containing the letters of the alphabet $\Sigma$, and closed under $+$, $\cdot$ (concatenation) and $(\_)^*$. Then the induction is easy:

If the expression is $a$ (a letter), the language is generated by the grammar $S\rightarrow a$, where $S$ is the axiom. If the expression is $A+B$, by induction you have a grammar which generates $A$ and one that generates $B$, let us call their axioms $S_1$ and $S_2$. Then $S\rightarrow S_1 \mid S_2$ together with the rules of the other grammars generate $A+B$.

Try to do it with the other constructions (concatenation and Kleene star), it is not that difficult to see how it works!

Comment: Okay - is the `axiom' the start symbol? I think I understand your construction. I'm not sure how to go about the concatenation though. Can you help me out?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the case for concatenation is extremely similar? If $A \cdot B$, then similarly we have $S \rightarrow S_1S_2$ generating $A \cdot B$.

Comment: @Newb: Yes it is!

Comment: How does the case for the Kleene Star work though? I didn't figure that one out.

Comment: Suppose the expression is $(E)^*$ and you have a grammar that generates $E$, with axiom $S$. So you have to generate the empty word, $E$, $E\cdot E$ and so on. $S'\rightarrow \epsilon \mid S\,S'$ does exactly this. You should now prove that the languages generated by this grammar and by $(E)^*$ are the same!

Comment: The formulation of the proof depends on the knowledge you already have. If you have been told that the family of context-free languages is closed under union, concatenation and star, you do not have to repeat those constructions in your argument. Just apply that knowledge here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a regular language.Then there exists a DFA $N=(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,F)$ such that $L(N)=A$. Build a context-free grammar $G=(V,\Sigma,R,S)$ as follows:

Set $V=\{R_i \mid q_i \in Q\}$ (that is, $G$ has a variable for every state of $N$). Now, for every transition $\delta(q_i,a)=q_j$ add a rule $R_i\to aR_j$. For every accepting state $q_i∈F$ add a rule $R_i \to \epsilon$. Finally, make the start variable $S=R_0$.